# For Loop not working and cloning Javascript

Tags: javascript, for-loop, cloning

I've tried all sorts of things to figure out why my code isn't however, I can't seem to find out why. `

```js
    var numberOfFaces = 5;
    var theleftside = document.getElementById ("leftSide");
    var top_position = Math.floor((Math.random() * 400) + 1);
    var left_position = Math.floor((Math.random() * 400) + 1);
    var theRightSide = document.getElementById("rightSide");

    function generatefaces () {
      for (var i = 1; i < numberOfFaces; i++) {
        var img = document.createElement("img");
        img.src = "smile.png";
        img.style.top = top_position + "px";
        img.style.left = left_position + "px";
        theleftside.appendChild(img);

      }
    }
```

```css
  <style media="screen">
    img {
        position: absolute;
    }
    div {
        position: absolute;
        width: 500px;
        height: 500px;
    }
    #rightSide {
        left: 500px;
        border-left: 2px solid black;
    }
  </style>
```

```html
<h1>The Matching Game</h1>
    <p>Click on the extra smiling face on the left.</p>
    <div id="leftSide">
    </div>
    <div id="rightSide">
    </div>
```

`

I am trying to generate 5 images (smiley faces) on the lefside div at different positions, then trying to clone it to the right hand side,

I'm new with JS, so hints and tips would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Because you just implemented a function but did not call it. Try adding

```
generatefaces();
```

at the end.

Answer (score 0):

Two fold firstly you need to, as burkay says, call the function `generatefaces()`.

Secondly you need to create a second element for the right side using `img.cloneNode(true)` this creates a duplicate so you can then append that to the right side.

Also you are generating the random position outside of the loop so the same random position is used for each `img` you instead need to create a random position for every `img` by moving it inside the loop.

**Example:**

```js
var numberOfFaces = 5;
var theleftside = document.getElementById("leftSide");

var theRightSide = document.getElementById("rightSide");

// You need to call this function
generatefaces()

function generatefaces() {
  for (var i = 1; i < numberOfFaces; i++) {
    // Generate the new random position for each img
    var top_position = Math.floor((Math.random() * 400) + 1);
    var left_position = Math.floor((Math.random() * 400) + 1);
    var img = document.createElement("img");
    // The location of your face image
    img.src = "https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/5/54/Emojione_1F60E.svg/64px-Emojione_1F60E.svg.png";
    img.style.top = top_position + "px";
    img.style.left = left_position + "px";
    // Creates a duplicate version of the image
    var imgright = img.cloneNode(true);
    theleftside.appendChild(img);
    // Appends the duplicate image to the right side
    theRightSide.appendChild(imgright);
  }
}
```

```css
img {
  position: absolute;
}

div {
  position: absolute;
  width: 500px;
  height: 500px;
}

#rightSide {
  left: 500px;
  border-left: 2px solid black;
}
```

```html
<h1>The Matching Game</h1>
<p>Click on the extra smiling face on the left.</p>
<div id="leftSide">
</div>
<div id="rightSide">
</div>
```

Hope this helps!